# How can I prevent lstlisting with shadowbox-style to be split?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I have my listings styled with `frame=shadowbox`. In some cases the lower or upper border of a listing appears on the previous or next page (see screenshot). I do not wrap the listing in a `minipage` because I do not want to prevent general splitting of listings.

**How do I prevent the border of a listing being put on the next or previous page?**

[image: shadowbox border appears on next page]

Comment: declare it as a float!

Comment: You can use the float option (see [section 1.4 of the manual](http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)). It is used as `\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={Caption goes here},label={cod:lbl}] ... \end{lstlisting}`. The `caption` and `label` are optional, but is a good idea to use them if your code is going to be floating around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap *this* listing in a minipage:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[...]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

This will, of course, produce a bad page break.

Postpone all such adjustments to the final revision of your document. With some luck, a couple of `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` might save your page shape.

An alternative is to declare the listing as a float, see the manual.